# Momentum operator and Space operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, commutator, observables

This may be a silly question, but given that the momentum operator (say in the $x$-direction) can be written as $$p_x = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x},$$ would it be correct to say that $$p_x^2 x = - i\hbar p_x,$$ where $x$ is the position operator in the $x$-direction?

Comment: Can you explain *why* do you think the equality should hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it wouldn't, because those operators are meant to be applied to some wavefunctions, so that (in the position basis) :
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{p}^2\hat{x}\psi(x) 
   &= -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(x\psi(x)) \\
   &= -\hbar^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\psi(x) + x\psi'(x)) \\
   &= -\hbar^2(2\psi'(x) + x\psi''(x)) \\
   &= (-2i\hbar\hat{p} + \hat{x}\hat{p}^2)\psi(x) 
\end{align}
$$
hence $\hat{p}^2\hat{x} = \hat{x}\hat{p}^2 - 2i\hbar\hat{p}$. Actually, this result is a consequence of the canonical commutator $[\hat{x},\hat{p}] = i\hbar$.

Answer (score 3):

The equation
$$p_x = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
is an operator equation, i.e. its left and right
side are meant to operate on a wave function.
So this actually means
$$p_x\psi(x) = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x) \tag{1}$$
for *every* function $\psi(x)$.

Therefore your second equation actually means
$$p_x^2 x \psi(x)= - i\hbar p_x \psi(x) \tag{2}$$
or using (1)
$$-\hbar^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}x \psi(x)= -\hbar^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi(x) $$
which is obviously wrong.